# Can't get article to expand full width of page

Tags: articles, submenu

I am using Joomla 3.10.4 and I have made a drop down menu that displays submenu's that display a single article when clicked on. However when it pulls up the article it doesn't take up width of the page like it should - I can tell by the colored background behind the text and if I move the text it just smushes. I have made sure that there wasn't anything like a module next to it. What can I do?  [image]

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  To familiarise yourself with our community, please take our [tour] and read our [help] pages while you wait for support/feedback.  If you have attempted any techniques to resolve this problem, please [edit] your question to express what has not worked.  If you find a technique that resolves your question, you are welcome to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: If it is publicly available, can you provide a link to the page so that people can see the HTML/CSS behind your menu to help you further?

Comment: Website is legacyit.net using the JSN Finance Template. It looks like this is fixed now. Could the question author please provide the solution for anyone else that encounters the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the element of the div surrounding the post, there may be a max-width here.

Comment: Thank you for attempting to help, but if the question is missing the necessary details to confidently offer specific resolving advice, please wait to answer until the question has been edited (This prevents "wild guesses" from littering a page.  I'm not calling your post "trash".)